# Read and write to Redux store from multiple pages of a Gatsby App

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, gatsby

My app is like this:

Gatsby project

index.tsx - Entry point of app - I call

```
<Provider store={store}>
   <HomePage />
</Provider>
```

HomePage.js uses `mapStateToProps` and uses `connect(mapStateToProps)(HomePage)`

Inside my HomePage, of course I use multiple React components. And I can make use of the store, read/write of anything that happens on that `HomePage`.

On my Homepage, I have links to `ActivityPage`. Once I click on this page and land there - problem starts.

ActivityPage makes use of multiple sub-components to achieve tasks. How do I access read/write from ActivityPage?

I am unable to `useDispatch` to write or even read from the store. I can see the store on my ReactDev tools, but on trying to read/write I get 11 errors, mostly along the lines of I need to wrap Components with `<Provider>`

I read different solutions on Stack Overflow which suggested that I need to have `mapStateToProps` and use `connect` on whichever Component I need access the store.

This is not working, as I am specifically looking to get access to the store from a 'new page'. Do I need to go and make another store for my child pages? Help please.
**[image: error stack trace]**:

Comment: Is `ActivityPage` a React component? Is it a child or grand-child of the `HomePage` component?

Comment: ActivityPage - React component - Child
Structure of my project:
```<HomePage /> ===> <ActivityPage /> ==> <CustomCheckbox />
Parent => Child => G.Child```

Comment: and what kind of `link` gets you to `ActivitiyPage`

Comment: I am using `import { Link } from 'gatsby';` then on a button Click on <HomePage /> I am loading my ActivityPage like this

```<Link to="/ActivityPage"> Visit ActivityPage </Link>``` ActivityPage is a functional React Component

Comment: I found something along the lines of - I have to wrap it with a root element, but I don't understand how to apply this in this scenario

https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/using-redux

Comment: You could have a different `Provider` with the same `store`.  That would be really unusual but I think it should work.  It needs to be the same store instance or else each page will have a separate redux state.  For a typical React app, you would put the `Provider` in your highest level `App` component around everything, but I guess Gatsby pages are all independent.

Comment: There is some discussion that you want the same store instance across every page for the browser rendering, but separate instances with an initial state for the SSR version: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/pull/11134

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your component **must** be inside of a redux `Provider` component in order to use the redux hooks `useSelector` and `useDispatch` or the `connect` HOC.

In a typical React app you would place the `Provider` in your `App` component which is a parent of everything.  However Gatsby uses a different setup where each page is totally independent, so there is no shared parent where we can place the `Provider`.

What Gatsby does *have* is an API for overriding customizing behaviors by defining functions in configuration files.  There are a bunch of files that you can place in the root of your app, in the same folder as `package.json` and outside of `src`.  The two that we will use here are [`gatsby-browser.js`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#introduction), which controls the client-side, and [`gatsby-ssr.js`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-ssr/), which controls the creation of static HTML pages through server-side rendering.  Both of these files support a function called [`wrapRootElement`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-ssr/#wrapRootElement).

We use the `wrapRootElement` function to place our Redux provider as a wrapper around every page.  Since we are using the same function in two files, the official "using-redux" example defines that function in a separate file and imports it into both of the configurations. `wrap-with-provider.js` is not a special file name, it's just a holder for the function.

A `wrapRootElement` function receives the `element` as a prop which is similar to the `children` prop.  Our function creates a store instance and returns a `Provider` with that store which has the `element` as its child.  We are creating the store in this function, so if your current redux file is exporting a created `store` as a constant, you'll want to export a callable function that creates the store instead.  You can see their example [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/examples/using-redux/src/state/createStore.js).

[wrap-with-provider.js](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/examples/using-redux/wrap-with-provider.js)

```
import React from "react"
import { Provider } from "react-redux"

import createStore from "./src/state/createStore"

// eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name,react/prop-types
export default ({ element }) => {
  // Instantiating store in `wrapRootElement` handler ensures:
  //  - there is fresh store for each SSR page
  //  - it will be called only once in browser, when React mounts
  const store = createStore()
  return <Provider store={store}>{element}</Provider>
}
```

Again, this file does not manipulate Gatsby behavior on its own.  We need to export its value and assign it to a special variable in a configuration file to do that.  Here are those files:

[gatsby-browser.js](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/examples/using-redux/gatsby-browser.js)

```
import wrapWithProvider from "./wrap-with-provider"
export const wrapRootElement = wrapWithProvider
```

[gatsby-ssr.js](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/examples/using-redux/gatsby-ssr.js)

```
import wrapWithProvider from "./wrap-with-provider"
export const wrapRootElement = wrapWithProvider
```

The content is the same in both.  All we are doing is importing the function that we created in `wrap-with-provider.js` and assigning it to the special named variable `wrapRootElement` which controls behavior.

Comment: Thank you for this, its my weekend project, so took longer to get it working. If I am honest, I got the core idea from your answer and there were some bits that helped me a lot when I used this [Freecodecamp blog](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-started-with-gatsby-2-and-redux-ae1c543571ca/). Leaving it here for other readers, if they find it useful as I did. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted already and the Freecodecamp link posted in the comment were both really helpful resources, however for my specific use case I found looking at the Gatsby repository on redux the most helpful": https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/using-redux

Also, I ended up realizing that sessionStorage was more appropriate for my use case as I was trying to store data beyond a page refresh and I wasn't using the other features Redux offered. You can read more about localStorage here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage
and the differences between Redux and local storage here: [Why redux instead of session storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56923481/why-redux-instead-of-session-storage/56946696)

Also if you're using Redux I highly reccomend the redux-devtools extension for debugging you can install the package here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@redux-devtools/extension and the browser extension here:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en